# Variable change is not seen after button action

Tags: java, swing

```
package gameprojekt;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

//The GameWindow class holds the window
public class Game extends JFrame {

    /*Global variable declaration*/
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int windowXPos;
    private int windowYPos;

    public static String p1 = "Player1";
    public static String p2 = "Player2";

    public static int playerScore = 0;
    public static int oponentScore = 0;

    public static int player1X;
    public static int Player1Y;
    public static int player2X;
    public static int Player2Y;

    private static boolean running = true;

    public static int status = 0;
    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong"); 
    //public TestDrawPanel testPanel = new TestDrawPanel();

    public static int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public static void setStatus(int status) {
        Game.status = status;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Creates a new JFrame window with the given size and
     * center it based on the screen resolution
     */
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public Game() {
        /*Local variable declaration*/
        //JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        width = (int)dim.getWidth();
        height = (int)dim.getHeight();

        windowXPos = width / 2 - (width / 2) / 2;
        windowYPos = height / 2 - (height / 2) / 2;
        // ------------------------------------------------------------

        // Set size, half of the screen resolution
        frame.setSize(width/2, height/2);
        // Allign the window to the users resolution
        frame.setLocation(windowXPos, windowYPos);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        // By exiting the window using "X" all relevant data is closed
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    /* zum Testen auskommentiert
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("test");
        this.drawPlayer(g);
    }*/

    /**
     * Draw the Player on the given location and with the given size
     * @param g Graphics object
     */
    public void drawPlayer(Graphics g) {

    }

    private static void gameLoop() {
        Menue m = new Menue();
        m.loadMenue(frame);

        while (running) {
            if (m.isStartPressed()) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }

        }
    }

    /**
    * Create the game and initialize the gameplay
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*Variable declaration*/

        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        Game game = new Game();
        game.gameLoop();
    }
}

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package gameprojekt;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class Menue {

    /* Global variable declaration */
    private int widthMenue;
    private int heightMenue;
    private String start = "Start";
    private String highscores = "Highscores";
    private boolean startPressed = false;
    public JButton bStart = new JButton(start);
    public JButton bScore = new JButton(highscores);
    // ----------------------------------------------------

    public boolean isStartPressed() {
        return startPressed;
    }

    public void setStartPressed(boolean startPressed) {
        this.startPressed = startPressed;
    }

    public int getWidthMenue() {
        return widthMenue;
    }

    public void setwidthMenue(int widthMenue) {
        this.widthMenue = widthMenue;
    }

    public int getheightMenue() {
        return heightMenue;
    }

    public void setheightMenue(int heightMenue) {
        this.heightMenue = heightMenue;
    }

    public void loadMenue(JFrame j) {
        JPanel menue = new JPanel();

        LayoutManager border = new BorderLayout();
        menue.setLayout(border);
        menue.setBackground(Color.black);

        bStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setStartPressed(true);
            }
        });

        menue.add(bStart, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        menue.add(bScore, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        j.getContentPane().add(menue);
    }
}
```

Hi I'm having a problem that the variable `startPressed` seems to be getting ignored. If the button start is pressed the variable `startPressed` is set to true but the if statement in this while loop doesn't react to the new value:

```
        while (running) {
            if (m.isStartPressed()) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }

        }
```

If I add `System.out.println` or `Thread.sleep` inside the loop then the if statement recognizes the value and is giving me the output.

I thought maybe there is a main problem in the programming structure or Java is too slow. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you show two Game classes in your posted code above?

Comment: See: [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your startPressed variable is not made volatile, and thus changing it in one thread may not be reflected in another thread. Change this and you'll see that your start button changes this variable appropriately:

```
private volatile boolean startPressed = false;
```

Your game loop shouldn't be as it flies in the face of Swing threading rules. Why not use a Swing Timer (my preference) or if you need your own roll-your own loop, then doing so in a background thread. Also consider making startPressed a "bound" variable, one that when changed tells any property change listeners that its state has been changed. This would be better than constantly polling its value.

Another comment: your code overuses statics and would be much better organized if you got rid of most of your static modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like

```
while(running) {
    ...
}
```

it means, that this loop is executed over and over again, nothing stops it, it gets executed as fast as your PC can do it. And therefore, it tends to block everything else. So yes, your program structure is the problem.  Try to execute your game-loop in a separate thread. This thread can then update your view from time to time. Maybe think about to pause this thread from time to time or to schedule it in some way, so your view is only update every second (or whatever you want).